# How to upload/update a leased blob with azcopy?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

Is there a way using azcopy v10 to upload or update a blob that has a lease on it? I checked the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json), and also ran `azcopy copy -h | grep lease` but nothing showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `azcopy` does not support upload/update a leased blob. All the supported parameters are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#options). You can raise a feature request in github like this one: [custom headers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/242).

By the way, you can try [azure cli commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_upload) which supports the `--lease-id` parameter.